# Stop youtube from showing more videos once mine is done

Tags: youtube

I want to show a video on my company website, but once the video is done, it previews other videos.

How can I stop YouTube from displaying additional videos?

The link addition is only good if I link people to the video...but if they go to the video on their own, they are still subject to the additional videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
&rel=0
```

to your Youtube video URL. Example:

http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/3UBbKLjOK3A?autoplay=1&rel=0

Comment: this seems to work if I LINK the video...but if someone goes to my YouTube page, they are still subject to the extra videos. Is there anything to program IN YouTube??

Comment: @SnowboardBruin: that I don't know.